# HotTowel/Durandal view compose limitations

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I'm trying to implement SPA with HotTowel Template by John Papa.
Is there a limitation on how many levels of ko compose I can do?

In the shell.html it calls

```
<!-- ko compose: { model: router.activeItem .... } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Within my active view, I try to embed another view, and then I tried to embed another view and so on.

In home.html.

```
<!-- ko compose: { model: $data, view: view1 } --><!-- /ko -->
```

In view1.html, I do

```
<!-- ko compose: { model: $data, view: view2 } --><!-- /ko -->
```

In view2.html, I do

```
<!-- ko compose: { model: $data, view: view3 } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Problem is View3 is not called.

I confirmed this in the Chrome debugger trace, view3 is never called. 
Is there a limitation in how many levels I can go?
If so how can I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Michael

Comment: it just stopped to load after 3 levels ? .

Comment: I've noticed similar issues, especially when nesting multiple Knockout containerless controls. Put your bindings in a section element and see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I added <section> and in another instance <div> in the template file and it's working now.

Comment: Correct. It's not a direct limitation of Durandal. It's something going on with KO's containerless functionality. Can you report this issue to the KO group, providing your specifics? I can then help to put some additional "weight" behind it :)

Comment: I should add that this is a very strange thing to do...

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this in jsFiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vPcPL/

Comment: @RPNiemeyer I had some problem like this with Durandal 1.2. I found a workaround for that changes a line in knockout which is stated here as the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751104/dynamic-composition-using-knockout-and-durandal-doesnt-work

Comment: @EisenbergEffect But if you've upgraded to Durandal 2.0.1 you should rollback this change from knockout.

Comment: @EisenbergEffect A slight same type of trouble I am having multiple compose in my home.html and though I am returning promise on each activate it would not run asycronous.

Answer (score 4):

As you've now found out -you have to have a root element in your view (it explicitly states this in the [Durandal docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-View/)):

> The view has exactly one root element. Durandal requires this. If
>   comments are found at the root, they will be removed. In the case
>   where more than one root element is found, they will be wrapped in a
>   div.